# A Vandermonde-like identity, new or existing?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

From my effort of finding [Vandermonde-like identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216752/vandermondes-like-identity), I found out that if $n \le m-2$, then  $$\sum_{r=1}^{n+1} \frac{\binom{2r}{r}\binom{m+n-2r}{n+1-r}}{r+1}=\binom{m+n}{n}.$$
I am not sure if this is new or not. Any idea?

Note: $\binom{n}{r}=0$ if $n<r$ or $n<0$.

Comment: All 'these' identities have been already 'proven' and somehow finding a 'new one' is alike to solving a 'new' system of linear equations. See http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we seek to show that
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n+1}
\frac{1}{r+1}{2r\choose r} {m+n-2r\choose n+1-r}
= {m+n\choose n}.$$

We will assume familiarity with the generating function of the Catalan
numbers (which  seems like  a reasonable assumption).  This generating
function is given by
$$\sum_{r\ge 0} \frac{1}{r+1}{2r\choose r} z^r
= \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$$
so that
$$\frac{1}{r+1}{2r\choose r}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon} \frac{1}{z^{r+1}} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z} \; dz.$$

Note in particular that this generating function is analytic in a
neighborhood of the origin $|z|\lt 1/4$ with the branch cut
$[1/4,\infty).$

Furthermore introduce
$${m+n-2r\choose n+1-r}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n-2r}}{w^{n+2-r}} \; dw.$$

Observe carefully that this last  integral is zero when $r\gt n+1,$ so
we may extend the range of the sum to infinity.

This yields for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n}}{w^{n+2}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon} \frac{1}{z} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z} 
\sum_{r\ge 1} \frac{w^r}{(1+w)^{2r} z^r}
\; dz\; dw 
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n}}{w^{n+2}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z^2} 
\frac{w/(1+w)^2/z}{1-w/(1+w)^2/z}
\; dz\; dw 
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n}}{w^{n+2}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z^2} 
\frac{1}{z(1+w)^2/w-1}
\; dz\; dw 
.$$

Observe that with the principal branch of the logarithm
$$1-\sqrt{1-4z} = 2z + 2z^2 + 4z^3 + \cdots$$
and
$$\frac{1}{z(1+w)^2/w-1} = 
-1 - z\frac{(1+w)^2}{w} - z^2\frac{(1+w)^4}{w^2} - \cdots.$$

so that the contribution from the pole at $z=0$ is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n}}{w^{n+2}}
\frac{1}{2} \times (-2) \; dw = - {m+n\choose n+1}.$$

On the other hand the contribution from the simple pole at
$z=w/(1+w)^2$ which is inside the contour is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n}}{w^{n+2}}
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4w/(1+w)^2}}{2w^2/(1+w)^4} 
\frac{w}{(1+w)^2} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n-2}}{w^{n+1}}
\frac{(1+w)^4-(1+w)^3\sqrt{(1+w)^2-4w}}{2w^2} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n-2}}{2w^{n+3}}
((1+w)^4-(1-w)(1+w)^3) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n-2}}{2w^{n+3}}
(1+w)^3 \times (2w) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n+1}}{w^{n+2}}\; dw.$$

which yields
$${m+n+1\choose n+1}.$$

Collecting the two contributions we obtain
$${m+n+1\choose n+1}-{m+n\choose n+1}
= \left(\frac{m+n+1}{n+1} - \frac{m}{n+1}\right){m+n\choose n}
\\ = {m+n\choose n}$$
as claimed.

**Addendum.** In fact the above admits considerable simplification.

Write
$$-{m+n\choose n+1} +
\sum_{r=0}^{n+1}
\frac{1}{r+1}{2r\choose r} {m+n-2r\choose n+1-r}$$

and use the same integral as before for the binomial coefficient to
obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n}}{w^{n+2}} 
\sum_{r\ge 0} \frac{1}{r+1} {2r\choose r} \frac{w^r}{(1+w)^{2r}}
\; dw$$

which becomes
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n}}{w^{n+2}} 
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4w/(1+w)^2}}{2w/(1+w)^2}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n}}{w^{n+2}} 
\frac{1+w-\sqrt{(1+w)^2-4w}}{2w/(1+w)}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n+1}}{w^{n+3}} 
\left(1+w-\sqrt{(1-w)^2}\right)
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n+1}}{w^{n+3}} 
(2w)
\; dw 
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{m+n+1}}{w^{n+2}} 
\; dw 
\\ = {m+n+1\choose n+1}.$$

We may then conclude as before.

**Addendum, Feb 2021.**  For the first version to be  complete we need
the conditions on $\varepsilon$ and  $\gamma$ for the geometric series
to converge.  This requires $|w/(1+w)^2|  \lt |z|.$ Note that  if this
holds then  the pole at $z=w/(1+w)^2$  is guaranteed to be  inside the
contour  in  $|z|$  as  claimed.   We take  $\gamma  \lt  1$  positive
somewhere close to  zero and we then  require $\gamma/(1-\gamma)^2 \lt
\varepsilon \lt 1/4$ where the last  term is from the Catalan GF.  The
values  $\gamma=1/7$  and  $\varepsilon=1/5$  will  work.   This  also
ensures convergence of the Catalan GF series in the compact version.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a typo?  Try $n=1, m=2$.

$$\sum_{r=1}^2 \dfrac{{{2r}\choose r} {{3-2r} \choose {2-2r}}}{r+1}
= -1 \ne {{2+1}\choose 1}$$

Your formula doesn't seem to be true for any positive integers $m, n$

EDIT: The corrected identity is "known" to Maple:

```
> simplify(sum(binomial(2*r,r)*binomial(m+n-2*r,n+1-r)/(r+1),r=1..n+1));
```

$$\dfrac{\Gamma(m+n+1)}{\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma(n+1)}$$

Comment: there is a condition: $n \le m-2$ which I previously state wrongly as $n \le m+2$. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Ah, I think you want ${m+n-2r} \choose {n+1-r}$, not 
${m+n-2r} \choose {n+1-2r}$.

Comment: This is interesting how Maple simplify it. This may lead another meaning (other from mine) to this identity. Anyway, thanks for checking out. It is useful!

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the LHS as:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{1}{2+r}{2+2r \choose 1+r}{m+n-2-2r \choose n-r}
=\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{1}{1+r}{2+2r \choose r}{m+n-2-2r \choose n-r}
$$
one recognizes that this is a particular case ($a=2,b=2,c=m+n-2$) of the [Rothe–Hagen identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rothe%E2%80%93Hagen_identity):
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac a{a+bk}\binom{a+bk}k\binom{c-bk}{n-k}=\binom{a+c}n,
$$
valid for any **complex** numbers $a,b,c$.

Comment: great to recognize it is a Rothe-Hagen identity (+1)!