# About sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you are a cashier of a cinema, the ticket is $\$5$, there are N people in the queue, each of them are buying one ticket, $x$ of them have $\$5$ notes, and others have $\$10$ notes. These people are arranged randomly. If you start with no money in your hand, what is the probability of you failing to provide changes to any of them?

To solve this problem, I need to use the following identity:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{a}\frac{{a\choose n}{b-a\choose n}}{ (n+1){b\choose 2n}}=\frac{b+1}{b-a+1}, b \geq 2a \geq 0$$

How to prove it?

Comment: Yes, it holds. Why are you interested in such identity? Tell us more about it!

Comment: It comes from solving a question in probability. Suppose you are a cashier of a cinema,  the ticket is $5, there are n people in the queue, each of them are buying one ticket, x of them have {\$5} notes, and others have {\$10} notes. These people are arranged randomly. If you start with no money in your hand, what is the probability of you failing to provide changes to any of them?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\frac{{a\choose n}{b-a\choose n}}{{b\choose 2n}}=\frac{{2n\choose n}{b-2n\choose a-n}}{{b\choose a}}.$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^{a}\frac{{a\choose n}{b-a\choose n}}{ (n+1){b\choose 2n}}
&=\frac{1}{{b\choose a}}\sum_{n=0}^{a}\frac{{2n\choose n}{b-2n\choose a-n}}{n+1}=
\frac{{b\choose a}+\sum_{n=1}^{a}\frac{{2n\choose n}{b-2n\choose a-n}}{n+1}}{{b\choose a}}\\
&=\frac{{b\choose a}+\color{blue}{{b\choose a-1}}}{{b\choose a}}=\frac{{b+1\choose a}}{{b\choose a}}=\frac{b+1}{b-a+1}
\end{align}$$
where to obtain $\color{blue}{{b\choose a-1}}$ we applied the identity shown at [A Vandermonde-like identity, new or existing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563307/a-vandermonde-like-identity-new-or-existing)

Comment: Yes, thanks. Do you have any better ways about solving the original problem? It seems to be a simple everyday life problem.

Comment: @Mango No, I have not. How do you know that this problem has a simpler solution? If you have a better idea please feel free to share with the community.